# Application of Meyer-Itô formula to a convex (but not differentiable) function

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, distribution-theory

I am trying to apply a simple example of Meyer-Itô's formula, which generalizes the classical Itô's formula over convex functions (instead of twice continuously differentiable functions). Applied to continuous semimartingales, Meyer-Itô's formula can be summarized as (see Theorem 70 in Protter's book):

Let $X$ be a continuous semimartingale and let $f$ be a convex function. The following equality holds: \begin{equation}
f(X_t) = f(X_0) + \int_{0^+}^t f_-^{\prime}(X_s) \mathrm{d}X_s + \frac12 \int_{\mathbb{R}} L_t^x f''(x) \mathrm{d}x,
\label{meyer-ito}
\end{equation}

where the signed measure $f''$ is the second derivative of $f$ in the sense of distributions, and where $L_t^x$ is the family of local times of $X$.

Suppose for simplicity I want to apply this equation with a standard Brownian motion $W = \{W_t : t \geq 0\}$ and with the convex function \begin{equation}
f(x) = {
 \left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
   -x & \mbox{if } x < 0, \\
   0 & \mbox{if } x \geq 0.
  \end{array}
 \right.
}
\end{equation}

How to deal with the last term of Meyer-Itô's formula? How do I proceed once I have computed the second derivative of $f$ in the sense of distributions?

I don't really know where to begin to get an explicit integral for the last term. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't agree it should disappear. For instance, if f(x) = |x| instead, then f''(x) = 0 for x \neq 0 too, however in this case the last term should be replaced by L_t^0, the (Brownian) local time spent at 0. See the first formula displayed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanaka's_formula

Comment: In this case, I'd say $f(W_t)=-\int_0^t\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,0]}(W_s)dW_s+\int L_{t}^x\delta_0(dx)=-\int_0^t\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,0]}(W_s)dW_s+L_t^0$ because the delta measure at zero maps $x\mapsto L_t^x$ to its value at zero. However, I don't get the question: are you hoping for an integral formula of which kind?

Comment: My question aimed to develop an understanding of how to calculate the final term in a general sense. Initially, like @ThomasKojar, my immediate inclination was to assume it is zero, but it seems incorrect. In this example, I think however it translates to compute integrals with the Dirac distribution indeed, thank you. I think we should find $f(W_t) = f(W_0) - \int_0^t \mathbf{1}_{(-\infty, 0]}(W_s) \mathrm{d}W_s + \frac12 \int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta(x) L_t^x \mathrm{d}x$, and the last term is $L_t^0/2$.

Comment: Correct: there is the $1/2$ factor in Protter's formula. However, I think such formula cannot be simplified further unless we know what the distributional derivative is like, which is a case-by-case issue. If it is a delta measure at some point $a$, then we know that the last term is $L_t^a/2$; but in general we can't say much in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

First to be clear, there is even a generalization for discontinuous martingales see [The Ito-Tanaka-Meyer Formula](https://%20https://almostsuremath.com/2020/10/12/the-ito-tanaka-meyer-formula/)
 involving jumps

Theorem 2 (Ito-Tanaka-Meyer) Let $X$ be a semimartingale, $f\colon{\mathbb R}\rightarrow{\mathbb R}$ be convex, and $L^x_t$ be a jointly measurable version of the local times. Then,

\begin{aligned} f(X_t)=& f(X_0)+\int_0^t f^\prime(X_-)dX+\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty L^x_t\,f^{\prime\prime}(dx)\\ &\quad+\sum_{s\le t}\left(\Delta f(X_s)-f^\prime(X_{s-})\Delta X_s\right), \end{aligned}
almost surely, for each $t\ge0$.

We first compute the distribution second derivative for $\phi=-x1_{x<0}$ similar to [Delta Function and Heaviside Function](https://www.iist.ac.in/sites/default/files/people/IN08026/delta_function.pdf). Note that we have the formulas

$$-x1_{x<0}=\frac{|x|-x}{2}=\int_{-\infty}^{-x}y\delta_{y}dy.$$

Therefore, we have the distributional derivative in terms of the Heaviside $\phi'(x)=sgn(x)1_{x<0}=-(1-H(x))$. So the second distributional derivative will be $\phi''(x)=\delta_{x}$.

For the case of continuous local martingale (eg.1d-Brownian motion) we have that $L^x_t$ is bi-continuous (eg. (1.7) Theorem in Revuz-Yor) and so we can directly evaluate the last term.